# How to use ulitimate thread group in jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter

Hi how to use ultimate thread group and stepping thread group,

i was using this but cant get the result, can you please send me the screen shot of sample, using google sign in.

i followed this steps:

add jp@gc ultimate thread group,
under give the local host name,
then add listener , tree view

now run the group, no responses. nothing its happend,
i dont know to configure http Raw request jp@gc,need a simple screen shot of this scenario.

can you please tell me the full screenshot of this test scenario…..

example:

10 user was hold 10 min flipkart login page,if its done again 20 user is hold on 20 min on payment page,,,